# Google.Apis.Download.MediaDownloader retrieves "Not Found" pages

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have a C# application using the Drive REST API. First, it lists the files of the Drive with the "Files.list" endpoint. Then, the application uses the **Google.Apis.Download.MediaDownloader** to get the binary data of the listed files. From time to time, listed files get deleted before I have time to download them.

The **MediaDownloader** does not throw any exception and the **ProgressChanged** event reports a successfully completed download. The downloaded binary data is the html page "Google Drive - Page Not Found" instead of the file itself. A simple web HTTP request returns a 404 status code but the **MediaDownloader** seems to ignore it.

Is there a way to detect the 404 status code and still use the **MediaDownloader**?

I use this class because it already supports the chunked download and the cancellation token.

Here is the code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the file binary data from Google Drive.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="p_DownloadUrl">The file download URL.</param>
/// <param name="p_DriveService">The Drive service.</param>
/// <param name="p_Stream">The stream.</param>
public void GetFileData(string p_DownloadUrl,
                        IClientService p_DriveServicer,
                        Stream p_Stream)
{
    MediaDownloader downloader = new MediaDownloader(p_DriveService);
    downloader.ProgressChanged += progress => {
        if (progress.Exception != null) {
            throw progress.Exception;
        }
    };

    downloader.DownloadAsync(p_DownloadUrl,
        p_Stream,
        m_CancellationToken)
        .WaitAndThrowOnFailure();
}
```